# Fatal Error : Class 'Guzzle\Http\Client' not found in Laravel Even after Guzzle installed

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing an issue in a laravel project.
It's showing this error

> Fatal Error : Class 'Guzzle\Http\Client' not found

I have Guzzle installed and added to configuration file. Also I have added the `use GuzzleHttp\Client;` in my Controller but still its showing the error.

This is the code am using:

> $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();

Anyone please help.
Thanks

Comment: are you certain you have guzzle in your project? what laravel version are you using?

Comment: laravel version is 5.5

Comment: go to the root of your project, and run `composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle`

Comment: Its already installed "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6.0",

Comment: declare guzzle at the top of your controller as such; `use GuzzleHttp\Client;` and to call it in your function use this; `$client = new Client();`

Comment: check this `var_dump(class_exists('GuzzleHttp\Client'));`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class 'Guzzle\Http\Client' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941668/class-guzzle-http-client-not-found)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed a **'\'**. Add it and will resolve the issue.

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

If you will add it on the top of your controller like

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleHttp;
```

then you can access it just by

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp();
```

> I have used **as** because there may be **Client** already in use.

***If you have added class into aliases in config/app.php like***

```
'GuzzleHttp' => \GuzzleHttp\Client::class
```

***then just use it like this in controller***

```
use GuzzleHttp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a minor mistake. Please add the ***'\'*** with `GuzzleHttp\Client();` like given below:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
```

For reference, you can check the documentation here

> https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

## Send an asynchronous request.

You can send an asynchronous request like this:

```
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org');
```

If it doesn't work, please try to update the Guzzle as per your laravel version:

You can then update Guzzle using composer:

```
composer update
```